# How is Elasticsearch calculating the scores in this Function Score Query? Strange behaviour

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a `script_score` to calculate the score based on the value of a field, let's call it `likeability` it is of type `float`.

The script is:

```
_score * (1 + _doc['likeability'].value)
```

I have some identical documents except for the `likeability` and the id of course.

When I run the function score query as below, I get the following results:

```
id | likeability | score
A  | 3.5         | 56.961056
B  | 2.0         | 37.974037
C  | 1.5         | 31.645031
D  | 0.5         | 18.987019
E  | 1.0         | 16.044298
F  | 0.0         |  8.022149
```

Strangely with a likeability of `0.5` document D gets a higher score than E with a likeability of `1.0`.

Has anyone an idea of why this is the case?

I had this problem on my machine and it disappeared. But now is happening on another machine.

Can this have something to do with the number of shards?

Here is my query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": { ... }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "_score * (1 + doc['likeability'].value)",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "boost_mode" : "replace",
      "max_boost": 3.4028235E+38,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I double checked again, and as it seems it might have to do something with shards, because if I calculate the `_score` out of the script it turns out there are two values for it:

```
id | likeability | score

_score of 12,65777
A  | 3.5         | 56.961056
B  | 2.0         | 37.974037 
C  | 1.5         | 31.645031 
D  | 0.5         | 18.987019 

_score of 8.022149
E  | 1.0         | 16.044298 
F  | 0.0         |  8.022149
```

Comment: It depends on your query, really. Documents that match a given set of criteria could still have a high score that is independent from "likebility"

Comment: All values of all fields mostly text (except likeability and id) are identical. The query is a simple match term query with some boosting per field. But again, all values/texts are identical.

And it works on some machines and doesn't on others. 

It is default with 5 shards and ES 5.5.

Comment: May you please specify what "works on other machines" means? Do you have several installations of ES, or several machines in one cluster?

Comment: what does the _explain API shows you?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html for the sharding issue. Generally you either have enough data that it doesn't matter or you should use a single shard. Maybe shrink down to 1 shard and run the queries again?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev: I had it running locally on my machine and on a machine in a docker container.


It worked in my local test setup because there was just one shard configured while in the docker container the default of 5 shards was set. So it really was a sharding issue. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @xeraa
I had not enough data, because I was writing a test. And just inserted 5 items. This seems to be the Problem. If you write an answer I can then mark it as solved. Otherwise I will add an answer myself in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the problem came down to too many shards and too little data. The issue is described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html in detail, but the problem in general is that the IDF part of TF/IDF. It keeps statistics how common a term over all the documents (in one field) is. Rare terms are more "valuable" and get a higher score. However, contrary to intuition this statistic is calculated per shard. If your data is unevenly distributed, your scores will be off.

There is also the option `?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` to calculate overall statistics, but this really shouldn't be necessary. You either have enough data that it doesn't matter or you should use a single shard.